# How to Setup-and-Deploy Application with MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, setup-deployment

How do I Include MYSQL Workbench Database/Schema on my VB.NET Application when i do the Setup-and-Deploy procedure, been finding a way to include my database on my application, can't find anything, i really need help, please answer

Comment: MYSQL Workbench is a tool, should we assume you mean a MYSQL database

Comment: yes a MYSQL database, used it as back end, how do i make it work on a client pc?

Comment: You would have to include the MYSQL Install and a database that you would have to restore into the newly installed MYSQL. Or make your code spot the database is missing and create the database and load any initial values to tables when it first gets run. Not a simple task.

Comment: i'm not really professional in using vb.net so can you please somehow show or teach me how to make a code to spot that my database is missing